# UPI payments response on web

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, payment-gateway, web-development-server

I am trying to integrate UPI payments in an app and website. Everything works fine when I form the url (an example below) and launch an `Intent` on Android.

```
upi://pay?pa=abc@xyz&pn=ABC
```

I get the `response` in the calling Android app using `onActivityResult` but I am not sure how do we get the response if we launch the PSP app (Google Pay or BHIM) from a website on the phone.

Any pointers in how can I get the response or if there is a way to specify a callback url?

Answer (score 1):

The NPCI UPI Linking Specification states that the URL parameter used in the payment link is for information purpose which the payment apps may use to provide additional information to the payer upon clicking the link.

The link is only expected to show transaction details by the merchant or party that invoked the transaction.

It is **not meant as a callback** URL or a web hook for completion of transaction and cannot be used to get transaction response.